# How to send and receive text data to other device using Bluetooth in my Flutterflow project

Tags: ios, bluetooth, flutterflow

I have tried so much times to send and receive text data to other device using Bluetooth in my FlutterFlow project.
I'm using flutter blue plus 1.7.5 version now.
I can display nearby and connected device lists. But after refresh, all list is disappear. how to fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant code in `code blocks`.  There is no generic way of sending data to all BLE peripherals.  You need to know what characteristic ids your peripheral uses and the data format it expects